# Solve $f'(x)f''(x)=\frac12$ without using differential equations

Tags: calculus, functions

The task seems to be trivial:

Twice differentiable gunction $f(x)$ maps segment of real numbers $[0,\infty)$ onto the same set of real numbers $[0,\infty)$ (each non-negative real value of $f(x)$ has a corresponding non-negative argument $x$). Find all functions $f(x)$ that satisfy the following criteria:

$$f'(x)f''(x)=\frac12$$

This differential equation is trivial and you don't need more than a few rows to prove that

$$f(x)=\frac23x^{\frac32}$$

However, the ask is to solve the problem **without using approach based on differential equation!** Any ideas?

Comment: Begin by assuming f(x) is monomial. Obtain a condition on its degree.

Comment: by inspection? it is obvious that $f' \sim x^{a}$ because otherwise the exponents on the lhs wouldn't cancel such that we get a constant when multiplying. It follows that $x^{2a-1}=x^0$ so $a=1/2$...etc.

Comment: I dont understand what are exactly the restrictions?

Comment: btw. what are your boundary conditions?

Comment: @asgeige It's just that the whole set of non-negative real numbers is mapped to the whole set of non-negative real numbers. It's not difficult to prove to that the function starts from (0,0) and is constantly increasing

Comment: What do you mean without differntial equations?

Comment: This function is clearly infinitely diferntiable so write it in as sum of infite serie. Then calculate the coefficents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution is as follows, although I don't know if this satisfies your requirement that the approach shouldn't be based on differential equations.

Let $g = f'$. Then $(g^2)' = 2gg' = 1$, by your hypothesis. Thus $g^2 = x + c_0$. As $g$ is defined on $[0, \infty)$, we must have $c_0 \geq 0$. Then as $g$ is continuous and $g^2 \neq 0$ on $(0, \infty)$, we either have $g = +\sqrt{x + c_0}$ or $g = -\sqrt{x+c_0}$. In either case we may integrate and obtain

$$ f(x) = \pm\frac{2}{3}(x+c_0)^{\frac{3}{2}} + c_1,$$

for some $c_1 \in \mathbb{R}$. Now as $f$ is surjective, it is not hard to see that we need $f(0) = 0$, so solving for $c_1$ gives all such functions are of the form

$$f(x) = \pm \frac{2}{3}(x+c)^{\frac32} \mp \frac{2}{3}c^{\frac{3}{2}}$$

for $c \geq 0$.